# ServiceStack - UserAuth "Id" is INT while RavenDb expects "Id" to be STRING

Tags: authentication, servicestack, ravendb

I am trying to implement ServiceStack Authentication and Authorization for RavenDb. ServiceStack UserAuth model has property "Id" as Int while RavenDb excepts "Id" to be String.

When I try to create a new user I get the following exception:

> Message=Cannot set identity value 'UserAuths/1-A' on property 'Id'
>   for type 'ServiceStack.Auth.UserAuth' because property type is not a
>   string.   Source=Raven.Client

Can I implement a custom_UserAuth table ignoring ServiceStack UserAuth table? Is that the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auth Repositories must at a minimum implement [IUserAuth](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Auth/IUserAuth.cs) but you can use your own concrete UserAuth Table which is what the [RavenDbUserAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Authentication.RavenDb/RavenDbUserAuthRepository.cs) allows by using the generic `RavenDbUserAuthRepository<TUserAuth, TUserAuthDetails>`.

E.g: you can create a custom `MyRavenDbUserAuthRepository` using your own `MyUserAuth` or `MyUserAuthDetails` classes:

```
public class MyRavenDbUserAuthRepository 
  : RavenDbUserAuthRepository<MyUserAuth, MyUserAuthDetails>, IUserAuthRepository
{
    public RavenDbUserAuthRepository(IDocumentStore docStore) : base(docStore) { }
}
```

Otherwise it looks like RavenDB lets you [customize which property to use as its Identity](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/client-api/session/configuration/how-to-customize-identity-property-lookup-for-entities).